# Is there solution to make TiddlyWiki support multi-user privilege

Tags: tiddlywiki

I'm using TiddlyWiki to share my knowledge. Before publishing the final contents, I want then to be revised by a small group of users. In this sense, I hope there are some way to limit the privilege of the specified pages so that someone cannot seen them, someone cannot edit them, while others have full privilege. Is there any plugin to do this? The solution is limited to TiddlyWiki 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of NoteSelf, which may suit your needs:

https://noteself.github.io

NoteSelf is a tiddlywiki edition that uses Pouchdb behind the scenes. This allows you to configure a remote couchdb-like database where you can synchronize to. Then you can configure several users for that database and allow different access levels. It's not tested on environments with lots of users, but it works for me with a couple of them.

My recommendation is to use the online version of it, which is available at

https://noteself.github.io/online

Comment: It's technically okay to use the same answer to more than one question, but much better to cater the answer to each specific question rather than using boilerplate.

Comment: It's not a boilerplate, it is just the same answer, written by hand for the first question I answered and the I just reused it again. I think that downvoting a valid answer just because it exist in another place it's just a way to discourage people to collaborate. I think that comment asking for an edit to focus the answer is a much more constructive and positive way. Also downvoting BOTH answers because the same reason demonstrates some kind of non necesary hate. Regards

Comment: They weren't my downvotes.  I can't answer to how anyone else voted, however.  Having both answers is okay, as I alluded to in the comment.

Comment: @jonsca I was not specifically talking to you, sorry if you felt alluded. I was talking to whoever down-voted both questions